Does QCoreApplication::quit quit local eventloops?
I've seen this pattern quite some times now:
QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
watcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run([]{ … }));
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(&watcher, &decltype(watcher)::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();

I wonder though if this is safe, because if qApp->quit(); quits this eventloop the code after it probably does not take into account that the thread may not be finished yet. So does QCoreApplication::quit quit local eventloops? And even if not is this pattern safe to serialize background tasks?

A very good question. I don't think it quits local event loops, but I am far from certain, so I'll leave the answer to someone who can (hopefully) say with certainty (and maybe links to documentation to prove it)

Yes, it does.
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFutureWatcher>
#include <QtConcurrent>


void localExec()
{
   auto *w = new QFutureWatcher<void>;

   w->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run([]{ QThread::sleep(10); }));

   QEventLoop loop;
   QObject::connect(w, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
   loop.exec();

   qDebug() << "is finished:" << w->isFinished();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTimer::singleShot(0, [&]{ localExec(); });
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, []{ QCoreApplication::quit(); });

    return a.exec();
}

is finished: false
Qt 6.5.3
